# Docker-compose deploy for Rasa 2.1.2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rasa-nlu, rasa

I just followed this documentation https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/docker/deploying-in-docker-compose/

Note: my assistant is on the folder mia-rasa-bot and their actions on mia-rasa-bot/actions.

My docker-compose looks like:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  rasa:
    image: rasa/rasa:2.1.2-full
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mia-rasa-bot:/app
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    command:
      - run
    depends_on:
      - app

  app:
    build:
      context: ./mia-rasa-bot/actions
    ports:
      - 5055:5055
    volumes:
      - .:/bot/actions

networks:
  default:
```

But when I execute curl:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook   -H "Content-type: application/json"   -d '{"sender": "test", "message": "hello"}'
```

I get the error:

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I guess that the path of your host bound to the volume is not writable. please double check the permissions.